# How to show the progress bar while downloading the database table data to Excel sheet in PHP/codeigniter

Tags: php

How to show the progress bar while downloading the database table data to Excel sheet in PHP?

Comment: show us what you have done until now.

Comment: 1. Create a database table with 6 columns, fill this table with 1,00,000 rows of dummy data.

2. Now create a PHP script which shows a "download as excel sheet" button.

3. On the click of "download as excel sheet" button, it will download those 1,00,000 rows of data as an excel sheet.

4. show progress bar or count of records worked on during the download.

 

once you have done the code, please share the code and data SQL file along with instructions for us to set up on our localhost for the demo.

Comment: you can use edit button in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <?php connect_local_host();?>
    <html lang="en">
    this is for the progress bar
    <body>
    <!-- Progress bar holder -->
    <div id="progress" style="width:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;"> 
     </div>
    <!-- Progress information -->
    <div id="information" style="width"></div>
    this code here is for exporting the query
    <?php
    function connect_local_host()
    {
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    $mysqlserver = "localhost";         
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $db = "allbanki_db";
    $link = mysql_connect( "$mysqlserver", $user, $pass );
    if ( ! $link )
    die( "Couldn't connect to MySQL" );
    //print "Successfully connected to server<P>";
    mysql_select_db( $db )
    or die ( "Couldn't open $db: ".mysql_error() );
    //print "Successfully selected database \"$db\"<P>"; 
    $query = "SELECT uacct_id,uacct_suid from user_account";
    $export = mysql_query ($query ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );
    $fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
    {
    $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";
    }
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
    {
    $line = '';
    foreach( $row as $value )
    {                                            
        if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
        {
            $value = "\t";
        }
        else
        {
            $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
    }
    $data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );
    if ( $data == "" )
    {enter code here
    $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";                        
    }
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=excel_data.xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    print "$header\n$data";
    //exit();
    //}
    // progress bar code again
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $time = $time_end - $time_start;
    $t_t=$time/$fields;
    $total = $t_t + 1;// added 1 to verify that the progress bar does work
    // Loop through process
    for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++){
    // Calculate the percentage
    $percent = floatval($i/$total * 100)."%";
    echo round($percent,0); 
    // Javascript for updating the progress bar and information
    echo '<script language="javascript">
    document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:'.$percent.';background-     color:#ddd;\">&nbsp;</div>";
    </script>';
    // This is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
    echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);
    // Send output to browser immediately
    flush();
    // Sleep one second so we can see the delay
    sleep(1);
    }
    // Tell user that the process is completed
    echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="Process   completed"</script>';
    echo '<br/>';
    echo  "Total time taken :"." ".round($time,6) . " s";
    }
     ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```